# How to switch to different user inside a shell script and execute some command with the new user?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, aix

I am currently logged into "SERVER1" with user "USER1", and i have placed my bash script here. This script has to switch to different user "USER2" on the same server "SERVER1" and execute some commands with the new switched user.

Note: USER1 is not a root user, so i need to specify the USER2 password inside the script, but in a encrypted format.

Please help me in achieving this..!

```
#!/bin/bash

command1
command2
.
.
...

echo "PASSWORD" | su USER2 << EOF
command1
command2
.
.
...
```

Please note, i don't want to change any configuration files here to achieve this.

Comment: Even if you manage to use `su` and pass the password using `expect`, the password needs to be plain text. Use `sudo` with `NOPASSWD` option. This will guarantee no one can steal the password from your script.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a good idea to store passwords in scripts, or attempt to stream them into `su`.  The better approach is to use `sudo`.

Since you're allowing USER1 to act as USER2 without a password, you can set up `/etc/sudoers` like this:

```
USER1 localhost=(USER2) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Then you can invoke `sudo` as USER1 as follows:

```
sudo -u USER2 bash
```

If you want to lock it down a bit more, you can specify a script that the user is allowed to execute.  The line in `/etc/sudoers` might look like:

```
USER1 localhost=(USER2) NOPASSWD: /home/USER1/setup.sh
```

And you would call:

```
sudo -u USER2 /home/USER1/setup.sh
```

Note in this last example, I think that USER2 would need to have an actual shell configured in `/etc/passwd` (i.e. NOT `/bin/false`).

Comment: ya.. i know this. I was just trying to get it done without touching `/etc/sudoers` file, as i am not a root user to edit it. Thanks for the reply..!

Comment: @Rohith: If there are painful limitations like "I can't add anything to `/etc/sudoers`", then you should list them in the question so that people can avoid giving you the obvious sensible answer when it doesn't meet your requirements because of the limitations.  (There's also a difference between "don't want to" and "do not have permission to" w.r.t "edit configuration files".)  If you can't hack `/etc/sudoers`, you may need to explore `expect` in combination with `su` or something similarly devious.  That's not a good solution; it might be a better solution, though.

Comment: If you don't have root privileges on that system, then what business do you have executing commands as another user?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sure will try that.

Comment: @paddy: I am from Automation Team, i don't have root privileges on the PROD servers, SysAdmins do. They might not agree to edit `/etc/sudoers`, will check with them. Thanks..!

Comment: `sudo` is definitely a better option.  A grungier option would be to use `ssh` along with `~/.ssh/config` to allow password-free sessions.